# IAR Embedded Workbench Interface with Python

Tags: python, iar

I am looking for Python API's for IAR Embedded Workbench, so that I can launch the existing project along with build generation and setting breakpoints and reading the data of variable. Please do let me know, if there are API's available for the same.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to use Pywinauto to get the element details, however I couldn't proceed further with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IAR Debugger's [target access plugin](https://github.com/IARSystems/cspy-target-access-demo) C API to read(/write) the target's memory and invoke it from the Python application.